# SQLite - Is there a way to open a SQLite Database with MySQL Query Browser 4?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Does any one know of a way to open a SQLite Database with MySQL Query Browser 4? I know it's a bit dated but it's still my favorite SQL Browser.

Currently I'm using MS Visual Studio but I really don't need something that powerful for just database editing.

Comment: SQLite != MySQL, so...... no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use the one from http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/